# Python Pandas Column to Minutes

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, timedelta

I've subtracted two datetimes from each other, like so:

`df['Time Difference'] = df['Time 1'] - df['Time 2']`

resulting in a timedelta object. I need the total number of minutes from this object, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Currently, the "Time Difference" column looks like this:

```
1     0 days 00:01:00.000000000
2     0 days 00:04:00.000000000
3     0 days 00:03:00.000000000
4     0 days 00:01:00.000000000
5     0 days 00:03:00.000000000
```

I've tried dividing by a numpy timedelta (which seems to be the most common suggestion) as well as by pandas timedelta, as well as a few other things. Operations such as `df['Time Difference'].seconds`, or `.seconds()`, or `.total_seconds`, (all suggestions I've seen for this), all give errors. I'm really at a loss for what to do here. I need this in minutes in order to make graphs in matplotlib, and I'm kind of stuck until I figure this out, so any suggestions are very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `df['Time Difference'].seconds` surely must work. Please include the full error message(s).

Comment: Can you provide full code, where df was initialized.

Answer (score 0):

use `dt.total_seconds()` and divide by 60 to get the minutes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'td': pd.to_timedelta(['0 days 00:01:00.000000000',
                                          '0 days 00:04:00.000000000',
                                          '0 days 00:03:00.000000000',
                                          '1 days 00:01:00.000000000',
                                          '0 days 00:03:00.000000000'])})

df['delta_min'] = df['td'].dt.total_seconds() / 60
# df['delta_min']
# 0       1.0
# 1       4.0
# 2       3.0
# 3    1441.0
# 4       3.0
```